# Monte Carlo Simulation of AR(1) in R but Demeaned

Tags: r, simulation, monte-carlo, autoregressive

Suppose that I want to run $i=100$ simulations of the following AR(1) model over 10 time periods:

$ X_{t,i} = 0.5(X_{t-1,i}-\bar{X}_{t-1})+e_{t,i} $

Here $ \bar{X}_t$ refers to the mean across the $i=100$, hence it is given by:

$ \bar{X}_{t-1}=\frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100}X_{t-1,i}$

How would I go about this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Generate one epoch $t$ at a time. Where is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute a simulated sample by using the recurrence relation. But, you need an initial sample that has the right variance and covariance between the different samples $i$.

You need to figure out the covariance of different pairs of variables

- Same time different series $\Sigma_1 = X_{t,i},X_{t,j}$
- Different time same series $\Sigma_2 = X_{t,i},X_{t+1,i}$
- Different time different series $\Sigma_3 = X_{t,i},X_{t+1,j}$
- Same time same series $\Sigma_4 = X_{t,i},X_{t+1,j}$

You can do this with your relationship

$$X_{t,i} = 0.495 \, X_{t-1,i}- 0.005 \, \sum_{j \neq i} {X}_{t-1,a}+e_{t,i}$$

Based on that you can make relationships between the covariances using the rules for [covariances of linear combinations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations).

I can get to

$$\Sigma_4 = Var(X_{t,i}) = 1 + (0.495^2 + 99 \cdot 0.005^2) \Sigma_4 + (2 \cdot 0.495\cdot - 0.005 \cdot 99 \cdot + 0.005 \cdot 0.005 \cdot 99 \cdot 98) \Sigma_1 = 1 + 0.2475 \Sigma_4 - 0.2475 \Sigma_1$$

And for the covariance $X_{t,i}, X_{t,j}$

$$\Sigma_1 = (2\cdot0.495\cdot -0.005\cdot + 98\cdot 0.005\cdot 0.005 ) \Sigma_4 + ( 2 \cdot 0.495^2 + 4 \cdot 98 \cdot 0.495 \cdot -0.005 + 97\cdot 98 \cdot 0.005 \cdot 0.005 ) \Sigma_1 = -0.0025 \Sigma_4 -0.2425 \Sigma_1 $$

From which it follows that

$$\Sigma_1 = -\frac{0.0025}{1.2425} \Sigma_4$$

$$\Sigma_4 = \left( 1-0.2475(1+  \frac{0.0025}{1.2425} 
)  \right)^{-1} \approx 1.328025 $$

and $\Sigma_1 \approx  -0.002672$

[image: example plot]

```
set.seed(1)

### computation of the covariance matrix of the samples within the same time
s4 = 1/(1-0.2475*(1-0.0025/1.2425))
s1 = s4*-0.0025/1.2425
Sigma = diag(rep(s4-s1,100))+s1

### compute the initial time
x = matrix(MASS::mvrnorm(1,rep(0,100),Sigma),100)

### compute new times using the recurrence
for (i in 1:10^2) {
   x = cbind(x,0.5 * (x[,i] - mean(x[,i])) + rnorm(100))
}

plot(x[1,],type="l", col = rgb(0,0,0,0.1), xlab = "time", ylab = "value")
for (i in 1:100) {
    lines(x[i,],col=rgb(0,0,0,0.1))
}
lines(x[1,], col = 2)
```

---

Alternatively a simpler derivation might be made by adding all equations together to get

$$\bar{X}_{t-1} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{t,i} =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( 0.5(X_{t-1,i}-\bar{X}_{t-1})+e_{t,i} \right) =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n  e_{t,i}$$

from which it follows that $\bar{X}_{t-1}$ is Gaussian noise.

We can now also compute the following

$$(X_{t,i}-\bar{X}_{t}) = 0.5(X_{t-1,i}-\bar{X}_{t-1})+e_{t,i} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n  e_{t,i}$$

which means that $(X_{t,i}-\bar{X}_{t})$ can be described by an AR(1) process. Although I am not sure how to continue. We can compute the variance of $(X_{t,i}-\bar{X}_{t})$, but we also need to know the correlation between $(X_{t,i}-\bar{X}_{t})$ and $\bar{X}_{t}$ in order to compute the variance of $X_{t,i}$.